# Find partial derivatives of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to find the partial derivatives (variational equations ?) and corresponding initial conditions of the following ODE:

$ \frac{d \vec{y}(t,\vec{y},u,\theta)}{dt} = f(t,\vec{y},u,\theta) = R \frac{u^{h}}{u^{h}+K^{h}}~-~l~\vec{y}(t,\vec{y},u,\theta)$

with $y_{0} = 1$, $~~~ \theta=\{R,K,h,l\}$ and $u = \rm const.$

I need to find the derivatives with respect to R,K, h and l. Here is what I have so far:

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial R} = \frac{u^h}{u^h + K^h} - l \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial R}
$

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial K} = \frac{-K^{h-1 }u^{h}Rh}{(u^h + K^h)^2} - l \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial K}
$

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial h} = \frac{-K^{h}c^{h}R(ln(K)-ln(u))}{(u^h + K^h)^2} - l \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial h}
$

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial l} = -\vec{y} - l \frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial l}
$

initial conditions for all four derivatives are $\frac{\partial y_{0}}{\partial \theta_{i}} = 0$

I am solving this system of ODEs (eq 5 coupled to eq 1) numerically to obtain the Jacobian of eq 1. Then I want to use the Jacobian for fitting the parameters using the levenberg-marquardt method. However, my solution does not converge to the true theta using the above analytically derived partial derivatives, only when approximating them numerically the solution converges. I believe I might have made a mistake in calculating these derivatives ?

Thanks brrrp

Comment: I got the same derivative, except you have some strange factor of $c^h$ in the third one. Is it a typo?

Comment: oh yes, sorry...it should be u^h in the third equation instead of c^h. Thanks for checking @Post No Bulls